# How to print Table of this format

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following data in mysql, and I want to echo in this format:

Data:

Name,Image URL,Link

I want to print it dynamically like this : http://screensaver.cf/screensavers.php

I don't know user's screen width, still I want it to appear as much as possible in width.

How can I do this in html and PHP?

My code:

```
<?php
    require("config.php");
?>   

<div id="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content"><div id='wsite-content' class='wsite-elements wsite-not-footer'>
<div class="paragraph" style="text-align:left;">
<?php

    $sql='SELECT * FROM `games` where 1=1';

    $data = mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<h4 class="result">Result:</h4>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)){

       $table=WHAT TO DO HERE TO MAKE IT LOOK LIKE THAT???????
       echo $table;
       echo '<br><br>';
    }
?>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    include("footer.php");
?>
```

P.S I know mysql is depreciated and I am constantly working to learn Mysqli, as I am in 8th class, I don't have much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
<style>.a{float:left;}
</style>
```

```html
> 
in while loop use this

<div class = "a"> 
<?php  <img src='".$row['url']."' width='140' height='140'> ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already go it!